# Как сократить код с 72 символов до 70?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: пробелы/табы/переносы строк убрать?

Comment: Новые версии студии умеют int Main без return компилировать?

Comment: @Ivan, аам... Ну как бы всегда умели, это не C/C++

Comment: @Ivan ну для начала `void Main`, а не `int Main`. Во втором случае нет, не умеют, но им и не нужно.

Comment: А как вы считали знаки? Нет, в ответе все ок, -2 знака, как просили, но исходное число 72 у меня ни как не сходится с реальностью

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
using static System.Console;
class A
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Write(ReadLine());
    }
}
```

-16 знаков (2 * "Console.") + 14 знаков ("Console" + "static ").

Comment: Самая быстрая клавиатура во всём диком Интернете!

Comment: Ну и можно метод сжать до выражения, если версия языка свежая

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov сорри, я не специально, а разница во времени прикольная получилась: 21 сек. =)